# xorg.conf to get current "Section "Device" content

Tags: xorg

by default the xorg.conf doesn't exist in /etc/

I could generate it by Xorg -configure. However in order to do this. I need to stop xserver. I can't do it at the moment.

So is it possible to get xorg's content or at least on option which is

> Section "Device"
>   (the driver line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you want need to set the `xorg.conf` file yourself since settings are automatically determined.

Most options can be guessed from the Xorg log at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (`0` is the display number). If you've an i5 or i7 processor, you're likely using the `intel` driver (the log will have a line with "(II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: ...").

If you still want to proceed generating the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, you need to run `Xorg -configure` as root without an active X server. Disabling the X server will make you loose your graphical session, so make sure that you've saved all work and logged out. When ready, switch to a virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and login the text console. First, stop the desktop manager: `sudo stop gdm` or if you're not using GNOME but KDE: `sudo stop kdm`. After that, you can run `sudo Xorg -configure`. After that, you can run `sudo start gdm` or `sudo start kdm` to get back to the graphical session. If not, (re)move the generated `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

Comment: and there is no way to get current xorg.conf without xorg stoppage?

Comment: AFAIK not, I tried the one described at http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9322591&postcount=6, but it did not work for me.

Comment: oh man it did work! "sudo X :2 -configure". But I see it's rather generic, I mean it doesn't contain any spefici to my current setup settings. But may be that's okay

Answer (score 3):

referring repeatedly to the assumption that it won't be necessary doesn't help those who have to. While the automatic startup does provide a functional Gui it is far from what the video card could really do.

xorg -configure on the other hand doesn't create a usable result, claiming that there are more devices than there really are (and so does the configuration look like)

For such issues it was extremely helpful to see, what the automate found and did when starting X as it is running now.