# How do I fix a corrupted mouse cursor?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xorg.conf to get current “Section ”Device" content](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57778/xorg-conf-to-get-current-section-device-content)

I have the same problem as here: [Mouse pointer strange problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21295/mouse-pointer-strange-problem). The mouse cursor is corrupted after a reboot, happens quite often.

I understand that I have to disable the hardware cursor and enable the software cursor, but how to do this?

**Reconfigure X**?

- One way may be to reconfigure the X server, but I don't currently have /etc/xorg.conf
- In order to get that file, I probably have to run X -configure?
- I cannot have X server running when doing that?

**How to stop the X server?**

- I can't reboot into rescue mode. I'm running Ubuntu on a USB stick ([Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)), and it says "can not find kernel image: rescue".
- There were some instructions how to get the rescue mode working (syslinux.cfg related) but those failed to work.

Any other ideas how to stop the X server and configure the X to get me a xorg.conf file?

**Xorg.d conf files**?

This sounds like a good bet: [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

I'm still having trouble to figure out what to put into a file that would define the proper device.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

X :2 -configure

Let's you configure X without stopping it. Found it here: [xorg.conf to get current "Section "Device" content](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57778/xorg-conf-to-get-current-section-device-content)